# Closed form and number of solutions for the zeros of exponential function?

Tags: calculus, roots

Consider the following equality

Is there any way to find the solutions of it in the closed form. Also, can we say anything about the number of solutions without solving it?

$$
(x+1)e^{\frac{(x+1)^2}{2a}}+(x-1)e^{\frac{(x-1)^2}{2a}}=4xe^{\frac{x^2}{a}}
$$
where we know that $x=0$ is one of the zeros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unlikely that there are closed-form solutions in general other than $0$. 
 If you're interested in real solutions, it looks to me like there are three if $a<0$ or $0 <a < 1/(2 W(e^{1/2})-1)$ where $W$ is the Lambert W function ($1/(2 W(e^{1/2})-1)$ being the value of $a$ where your function has derivative $0$ at $0$).

I say "in general" because you may be able to solve for $a$ that makes a given $x$ a solution.  If $x$ is rational, you get a rational function of $\exp(1/a)$.

Comment: Can we find the solutions using Lambert W function?

Comment: No, Lambert W will not help there.

Comment: Could you tell me how I can proceed and solve for $a$?

Comment: For example, $x=1/2$ gives you $\frac{3}{2} \exp(9/(8a)) - \frac{1}{2} \exp(1/(8a)) - 2 \exp(1/(4a))$, and with $t = \exp(1/(8a))$ this says $\frac{3}{2} t^8 - 2 t - \frac{1}{2} = 0$.  That's a polynomial (though not one solvable by radicals).

Comment: Could you help me to understand the condition on Lambert $W$ function which you mentioned $1/(2W(e^{1/2})-1)$ because I looked it up but not understand it. Where does it come from?
Can you show it for my problem?
Also, in my problem $a>0$ and I guess for  $1/(2W(e^{1/2})-1) \geq a$  the only zero of the equation is $x=0$. Is this correct? If so why?
I appreciate for your help.

Comment: Let $f(x) =  \left( x+1 \right) {{\rm e}^{1/2\,{\frac { \left( x+1 \right) ^{2}}{a
}}}}+ \left( x-1 \right) {{\rm e}^{1/2\,{\frac { \left( x-1 \right) ^{
2}}{a}}}}-4\,x{{\rm e}^{{\frac {{x}^{2}}{a}}}}
$.  Then $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0) = 2 (1 + 1/a) e^{1/(2a)}-4$.  That is $0$ if
$e^{1/(2a)} = 2/(1+1/a)$.  If we write $a = 1/(2s-1)$, that becomes
$ s e^s = e^{1/2}$.  The Lambert W function is defined so that $L(y)$ is a solution of $s e^s = y$.

Comment: Since $f(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \to +\infty$, if $f′(0)>0$ we will have at least one solution for $x>0$ (and by symmetry another for $x<0$, making three solutions). This is the case if $0<a<1/(2W(e^{1/2})−1)$.

Comment: On the other hand, if $f'(0) < 0$ it could be (and appears to be, from graphing) that $f$ is decreasing everywhere, in which case the only real solution is $x=0$

Comment: Can we some how force zeros to be overlaid at $x=0$, i.e. $x_1=x_2=x_3=0$ by putting a condition on  $a$?

Comment: If $a = 1/(2 W(e^{1/2})-1)$ we have $0 = f(0) = f'(0) = f''(0)$, so $0$ is a root of multiplicity $3$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Another question:-) If we use Taylor series of the 3 terms, we have $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(x+1)^{2k+1}+(x-1)^{2k+1}-(2)^{k+1}x^{2k+1}=0$ that does not depend on $a$, which is weird to me. Does this form help us to find the other two roots of the equation?

Comment: Could you tell me why that particular value of $a$ makes the second derivative to zero?

Comment: The second derivative at $0$ is $0$, as are all even-numbered derivatives there, because the function is odd.